# Inconsolata Italic in MacVim

Tags: fonts, macvim

I'm trying to use Inconsolata as my font in MacVim, but I can't seem to find an italic version. I'm using the solarized color scheme, which is supposed to italicize comments, and it works correctly for fonts that have italic or oblique versions in the Font Book.

Is there a way to "make" an italic version somehow? Is there some file I haven't been able to find?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a [LGC (Latin, Greek, Cyrilic) fork](https://github.com/MihailJP/Inconsolata-LGC) with bold and italic versions. In the [download section](https://github.com/MihailJP/Inconsolata-LGC/downloads) of the repository you can find the compiled .otf files ready to use.

Comment: Wow, serious points for answering an old question! I ended up using Liberation Mono instead, but may try to use inconsolata in the future.

Comment: I found the LGC fork to have much higher line height than the original Inconsolata (perhaps to accommodate the Cyrillic characters?), so I created a slight variant with shorter line height. .ttf files included. https://github.com/eggsyntax/Inconsolata-LGC-Short